# Replace a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a big database (20 Gb). The structure is like that:

```
  `Count` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Sensor Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` decimal(18,4) DEFAULT NULL
```

Now, I'm testing to reduce the size of database by using the 'sensorID' (int) instead of 'Sensor Name'.

```
 `Count` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SensorID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` float DEFAULT NULL,
```

I have an other table ('definition') to map between 'sensorID' and 'Sensor Name'.

```
CREATE TABLE  `definition` (
  `SensorID` smallint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Sensor Name` varchar(100))
```

So,how can I can replace the `Sensor Name` by 'sensorID' with the most efficient? Now, I'm using "SELECT" the 'Date' and 'Value' of each from old table and insert it to new table with the sensorID

```
INSERT INTO newtable (SensorID, `Date`, `Value`)
    SELECT 3681, `Date`, `Value` from oldtable where Sensor Name = 'abc';
```

with '3681' is the ID I got from 'definition' table
, but it takes me a week for 50% data. JOIN is not good ideal because with 20 Gb, it needs huge resources to do.

Comment: A VARCHAR will use a minimum of 1byte (for the length) then quite a few byte per character (1 to 4) (so between 1 to 401 bytes per sensor name), Using a `smallint` will use 2byte (always). So you will drastically reduce the disk usage if you don't have a lot of Sensor without a name (unlikely). So there is nothing to more prove...

Comment: exactly what I just commented under my answer; why to test if you already know that it uses a lot more memory. @Kien.N Put your time and RAM on something useful I would suggest.

Comment: PS: if it take you a week to work 10GB of data, first check if you have correct index to do the join... if this doesn't work, don't join an use a `cursor` to iterate the 20GB one line at a time or work with a subset of data. 10K row at a time...

Comment: Hi AxelH and Jorgen, I know the advantages of this work, this not only to prove the disk usage, but also, it is an experiment to learn a better way replace the column with less resource consumption in query and optimize the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create new table **Sensor** and populate all data in it.

update you old table's column data **Sensor Name** with new tables is like as follow.

```
UPDATE oldtable o INNER JOIN sensor s ON o.SensorName = s.SensorName
SET o.Sensorname = s.SensorId;
```

Then change the column name and type of oldtable's **Senson Name** to SensorID  as follow

```
ALTER TABLE oldtable CHANGE Sensorname SensorId INT(11);
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: `o.Sensorname = s.SensorId;` probably won't work, one is a numeric, the other is a text. It might need to create a new column `sensorId` to populate it then remove the `sensorName` column

Comment: Thank you for this demo, I will try with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the SensorID column to the existing table. Then run an update on that table. Something similar to this:

```
update SensorData s1, SensorData s2 SET s2.SensorId = s1.Id where s1.Id = s2.Id;
```

But please join another table to get the real SensorID (this is just the concept). If the update on the whole table takes too much performance, batch this query with limiting the where and run it a couple of times.

Comment: Mon goal is to test how many resources I can reduce by using other type of data (of course, we can estimate, but see the real is better), so, I don't want to change the existing table and avoid using JOIN if possible. You see, with 20 Gb data and about 8000 Sensor ID, if I use JOIN, the temporary table is huge, and it consumes RAM and I can't do other tasks with my server.

Comment: @Kien.N yes, I understand your question. What I say is: use a join on the subset (batch-wise) and run that until all SensorID fields are updated. I don't see the problem here. And I don't think a test is necessary here. If your names are long your small int takes less memory (both for index as data) and therefor MySQL is able to hold more of the data (and index) in memory, and therefor it is faster and uses less disk space. So my tip: fix it anyway. And you give the reason that it takes a lot of memory, but you already created a scenario that uses a lot of memory in the first place ;)